# How can I combining Webpack project output with Asp.Net project output in VSTS build?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

My repository contains an Asp.Net app, and a React app in seperate folder. I need to do a deployment to an Azure App service from a VSTS release.

Repository Root

- MyAspNetApp
- MyReactApp

The Asp.Net application is an MVC application. If it detects you on mobile it servers up the react app.

The react app is built using WebPack. When you do a production build, it copies the output into a folder called 'app' in the MyAspNetApp project. The production build can be run via 'npm run build-prod'.

When I was doing git deployments (kudu), I just added a command to the deploy.cmd to call 'npm install' and 'npm run build-prod'. Then another command to copy those files to the root of the deployment directory ('wwwroot').

Now that I am using VSTS to build and deploy (separate steps), I can't figure out how to get that 'app folder into wwwroot. In a build step I tried taking the stuff from the 'app' folder and putting it in an artifact called 'mobile'. Then in a deployment step, using a 'Copy Files' step to copy the 'mobile' artifact to $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/app, but they don't show up in wwwroot on azure.

What am I missing here?

edit: cross posted here in [MS VS Community site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/270159/adding-artifacts-from-webpack-to-aspnet-project.html) in hopes of getting a response. I will update this post if I get an answer there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Azure App Service Deploy task, if you check Publish using Web Deploy option, you need to put all necessary files in a zip file and specify this file in Package or folder input box.

You also can uncheck Publish using Web Deploy option and specify the root folder path of app.

Refer to these steps to do it:

1. Publish MVC application with File System publish method through Visual Studio build task
2. Run NPM commands to build React app through NPM task
3. Copy react app’s built files to necessary folder of MVC app deployed folder
4. (optional) Zip folder through Archive Files if you want to publish using web deploy
5. Add Azure App Service Deploy task (can be in release) and specify package or folder.

Comment: 1. Do you mean a Publish Build Artifacts task?

Comment: No, It is Visual Studio Build task with the argument `/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:publishUrl="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\" /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish` (Publish MVC web app with File System publish method)

Comment: Ok, this did work. I actually did my webpack (via npm script) before the VS build, as it copies those files in. The key here, was the changes to the VS build command in your comment above. T hen changing deployment to point to the drop folder instead of a zip file. Thank you.